# Magento Collection on Mysql4 = No such file or directory

Tags: magento

In a downloaded module there is a specific call `Mage::getModel('module/statistic_collection')`, this gives me the `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error with the path `Namespace/Module/Model/Statistic/Collection.php` but it exists in `Namespace/Module/Model/Mysql4/Statistic/Collection.php`.
So how can I tell magento that they need to add the `Mysql4` folder ?

Comment: try changing it from `Mage::getModel('module/statistic_collection')` to `Mage::getModel('module/statistic')->getCollection()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('module/statistics_collection')
```

or

```
Mage::getModel('module/statistics')->getCollection()
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much... In fact there was Mage::getResourceModel before but I read that getModel + getCollection == getResourceModel so I replaced it and got this error... So my problem wasn't that but I found where it was because of your tip :-)